# append button to many collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, append

i am developing using jQuery mobile with Cordova

i am having default to append a button to each collapsible

so basically i am like 50 collapsible and i wanna append the button to each one , this is my code but the problem that the append happen to first collapsible only not to everyone

code for create many () :

```js
                        var content = "<div data-role='collapsible' id='" + counter + "'><h3>order ID : " + obj[counter].order_id + "</h3><p>The order date : "+obj[counter].order_date+"<br>The labor name is : "+obj[counter].laboor_first_name+' '+obj[counter].laboor_last_name+"<br>Labor type : "+obj[counter].laboor_type+"<br>order status : "+obj[counter].order_status+" </p><div id='commentDiv' style='margin: auto;width: 15%;'></div></div>";
                        
                        $("#set").append(content).collapsibleset('refresh');
                        creatCommentAndRateBTN();
```

and this is the code for creatCommentAndRateBTN() that responsable for create the button for each collapsible

```js
function creatCommentAndRateBTN() {
                            // this block for create button with rating
                           var commentHTML=$('<input>').attr({
                            type : 'button',
                            id: "comment",
                            value: 'Comment & Rating', 
                        }).on({
                    'click': function() { $.mobile.changePage( "#dialog_checking", { role: "dialog" } ); } });
                        
                        $("#commentDiv").after(commentHTML).trigger('create');
                        $('#comment').buttonMarkup({ theme: "a" }); 
                       createDailogForCommentAndRating();
                        

}
```

the problem is all button create in one collapsible , like in the photo below

[image]

Comment: Well, you do seem to be adding them all after `#commentDiv`, are you expecting that to change? If you're using that ID in multiple places you will have problems (Use unique IDs, or Classes)

Comment: yes i am using same id , i tried to give the div unique id (like counter var) in the for loop because it's number but same problem